# Unknown Manifest after Docker pull in build pipeline when committing to GitLab

Tags: docker, gitlab

After pushing a commit to GitLab the build pipeline starts to check the new commit. Build and Test stage run successfully. But the Deploy stage stops with the following error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.3.0 (a8a019e0)
  on gitlab-runner2 QNyj_HGG
Using Docker executor with image nexus.XXX.com/YYY/ZZZ-engines ...
Authenticating with credentials from /root/.docker/config.json
Pulling docker image nexus.XXX.com/YYY/ZZZ-engines ...
ERROR: Job failed: Error response from daemon: manifest for
 nexus.XXX.com/YYY/ZZZ-engines:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown (executor_docker.go:188:0s)
```

What could be the reason behind that?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I solved it by rebuilding and republishing the docker image that the GitLab CI file was referencing and then re-run the pipeline again and it worked.

Comment: I tried retriggering the build, but no luck... this was triggered by a tag, so I changed the tag and worked. Not sure if it was a timely thing, depended somehow on the name (perhaps already existed and was deleted?) or just bad luck.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `latest` tag for that specific docker image. Most likely you're building [using a specific tag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#tag-an-image--t), e.g `v1.0`:

```sh
docker build -t nexus.XXX.com/YYY/ZZZ-engines:v1.0 .
```

then using that image without a tag in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
image: nexus.XXX.com/YYY/ZZZ-engines

# OR

build-job:
  stage: build
  image: nexus.XXX.com/YYY/ZZZ-engines
  ...
```

To fix, either specify a tag in you ci file, or tag the image with `latest` when building:

```sh
docker build -t nexus.XXX.com/YYY/ZZZ-engines:v1.0 -t nexus.XXX.com/YYY/ZZZ-engines:latest .
```

The gitlab docker template has a nice example of how to automatically tag a build as `latest` on the default branch: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Docker.gitlab-ci.yml